# Cloudflare Page Rules wildcard redirects

Tags: redirect, http-redirect, cloudflare

My old website, oldsite.com has incoming URLs that contain specific text strings in different parts of the URL that I want to forward to a newsite.com. Here are some examples:

- oldsite.com/STRINGccccc
- oldsite.com/ccccSTRINGcccc
- oldsite.com/ccccSTRING

where cccc is any text of variable length. All should forward to newsite.com/STRING

Is that possible using Cloudflare's Page Rules?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work if you had the url marked with something like *oldsite.com* to newsite.com. A pretty detailed [PageRules tutorial](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-).

Answer (score 1):

Hand to forehead for missing the tutorial when I searched for it. The solution could not be simpler.

```
oldsite.com/*STRING*
```